# Criteria based Query using ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

Problem: criteria for education is that it should be in 1 km buffer and have a population of 500. I want to identify which schools fulfill the criteria. I want to do analysis in ArcMap.

Can you suggest some tools or Python script to evaluate which school are according to criteria?

Comment: In one query is not possible as the tools allow either attribute query or location based. But its very easy to use the model builder for it. Just put your queries there via the tools from the toolbox (select by attribute and select by location).

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you can accomplish this.  The following instructions will show you how to select schools which have a population of at least 500 and are within 1km of some other layer. What you then do with that selection is up to you.  You can export them as another layer, or export the attribute table to a spreadsheet to name a few.

1. **[Select by attributes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-attributes.htm)** your schools which have a population >= 500. Depending on your data type, your selection may look something like this:

   `"POP">=500`
2. [**Select by location**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-location.htm) the schools from your current selection which are inside your 1km buffer. Ensure that you've set selection method to "*Select from the currently selected features in*".  Your target layer is your schools and your source layer is your 1km buffer.  Your spatial selection method can be INTERSECT or WITHIN.

That will select the schools within 1km of your buffer and have a population of at least 500.  There are other methods to achieve the same result. But I thought this was fairly straight-forward.